# Entity Framework: Exception with unsigned int as primary key

Tags: entity-framework

I'm making my first steps with EF. I have no problems to create a model and show some data as long as there is no unsigned integer column as primary key in the table.

All the columns defined as UInt32 in the database are mapped to an Int64 in the model. The programm compiles without any error but throws an exception "InvalidOperationException:
The type of the key field xx is expected to be System.Int64, but the value provided is actually of type System.UInt32"

Database is Sybase SQL Anywhere 11, Build 2913
Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4, but same with VS 2012 and .NET 4

What can I do?

Thanks

Michael

---

```
using (var f = new FritscheContext())
  {
    var s = f.CG_AUFTRAEGE;

    foreach (var det in s)
    {
     // ID_AUFTRAG_CG is an unsigned int as primary key
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", det.ID_AUFTRAG_CG, det.AUFTRAG_CG); 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("fertig. Taste drücken");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Comment: Why don't you use a `UInt32` type in the model instead of `Int64`?

Comment: 1. The DB was first (about 500 tables, nearly each with an unsigned int as PK). I created the model via Visual Studio from the DB as source, the UInt32 were automatically mapped to Int64.
2. Replacing all Int64 to UInt32 in the model source code gives a lot of compiler errors, because UInt32 is not supported as primitive type.